# How to do, If checkbox is checked it will uncheck the other checkbox?

Tags: google-sheets

I have three columns:

1. Task (text)
2. Assigned (checkbox 1)
3. Done (checkbox 2)

I want to create a ticket task sheet. If task is in progress, check **checkbox 1** and task cell will turn yellow. I'm able to make this work.

But what I can't get it to work is:
If task is completed, check **checkbox 2**, and will automatically unchecked **checkbox 1**, also, will change task color to green instead of yellow. I tried to use IF, SUBSTITUTE, or REPLACE but don't know how to get it to work.

Share and Edit link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IT-GoMUwbNgVcr1kJMtR-1GcWVQREjiRav7kweoeZcA/edit?usp=sharing

Best regards

Comment: Welcome. 
Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

`switch` can do the same job.

```
=switch(A2,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)
```

> Tests an expression against a list of cases and returns the corresponding value of the first matching case, with an optional default value if nothing else is met.
>       `SWITCH(expression; case1; value1; [case2_or_default; …]; [value2; …])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following formula for "In Progress" column

```
=if(C2=true,FALSE,true)
```

It will make only "Done" tick box active and "In Progress" depending on it.